# required in rules is not worked for select2 widget in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I had two drop down in form. I load value for second dropdown based on first dropdown's value.
In model I specified second dropdown as normal variable but it get 
input in multiple select.
I write required validation for both first and second drop down.

model

```
 */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['emp_id', 'role_team'], 'required'],
            [['emp_id', 'role_team'], 'integer'],
            [['status', 'team_status'], 'boolean'],
            [['type'], 'string']
        ];
    }
```

In form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 4,'showErrors'=>true,'showHints'=>true],]); ?>
<?php 
echo Form::widget([
                'model' => $model,
                'form' => $form,
                'columns'=>4,
                'attributes' => [
                'role_team' => ['type'=>Form::INPUT_WIDGET,
                'label'=>'Team',
                'widgetClass'=>'\kartik\select2\Select2',
                'options'=>['data'=>Teams::find()->select(['team_name'])->indexBy('team_id')->column(),'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Team Name','id'=>'team-category']]],
                'emp_id' => ['type'=>Form::INPUT_WIDGET,'label'=>'Employees',
                'widgetClass'=>'\kartik\select2\Select2',
                'options'=>['data'=> EmpDetails::find()->select(['emp_name'])->indexBy('emp_id')->column(),'options'=>['placeholder'=>'Employee Name','multiple'=>true,'id'=>'team-sub-category']]],
]
]);
?>
```

It has not throw error before submitting the form.

Comment: What kind of `Form` are you using here?

Comment: kartik active form

Comment: In another form also I using this same widget but the error validation is worked. By default kartik assigned id to all fields in that form but in my form I assigned my own id to select widget. Kartik form print the error using its default id. Then I removed the id and I used its default id.